# Visual Basic Keep validate InputBoxes in a Loop

Tags: vba, visual-studio

I am working on a Budget calculator for a class project. Basically everything works great except one little annoying nuance.

When you don't enter a number or you enter a negative number you get an error message. However, when you accidentally type in a letter, get the error, then type in the negative number it just exits, and I want it to show that error and loop back until they enter in a positive number.

I am using VBA in Visual Studio 2012, this is a Windows Form Application.

```
    Dim strEntertainmentHeading As String = "Entertainment Expenses"
    Dim strHeading As String = "Budget Alottment"
    Dim strNonNumericError As String = "Error - Enter a number for the Expense"
    Dim strNegativeError As String = "Error - Enter a positive number for the Expense"
    Dim strEntertainmentInput As String = "Enter the amount for Entertainment Expenses"
    Dim strEntertainment As String
    Dim decEntertainment As Decimal
    strEntertainment = InputBox(strEntertainmentInput, strEntertainmentHeading, " ")

    Do
        If strEntertainment = "" Then
            Exit Sub

        ElseIf IsNumeric(strEntertainment) Then
            decEntertainment = Convert.ToDecimal(strEntertainment)

            If decEntertainment >= 0 Then
                lstBudget.Items.Add("Entertainment Expense: " & decEntertainment.ToString("C2"))


                ' Display error message if user entered a negative value
            Else
                strEntertainmentInput = strNegativeError
            End If
        Else
            strEntertainmentInput = strNonNumericError
        End If

        If decEntertainment <= 0 Then
            strEntertainment = InputBox(strEntertainmentInput, strEntertainmentHeading, " ")
        End If

    Loop Until IsNumeric(strEntertainment) And decEntertainment >= 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course, you have this problem: decEntertainment is 0 by default and after asking for input the second time, you do not Convert.ToDecimal anymore.

You avoid this type of errors if you adopt a clear coding style, like

```
Do 
    strEntertainmentInput = ''
    strEntertainment = InputBox(strEntertainmentInput, strEntertainmentHeading, " ")

    If Not IsNumeric(strEntertainment) Then
        strEntertainmentInput = strNonNumericError
    Else
        decEntertainment = Convert.ToDecimal(strEntertainment)
        If decEntertainment < 0 Then
            strEntertainmentInput = strNegativeError
        Else
            lstBudget.Items.Add("Entertainment Expense: " & decEntertainment.ToString("C2"))
        End
    End
Loop Until strEntertainmentInput = ''
```

Comment: Thanks, that helped me to figure out what I needed to do. I was able to tweak your code and combine it with some of mine to get it to work. I appreciate the help!! Thank you very much!!